# Как правильно использовать findViewById

Tags: java, android, xml, view

У меня примерно следующая иерархия id:

```
<DrawerLayout>
    <CoordinatorLayout>
        <CoordinatorLayout>
            <FrameLayout> id=name1
                <FrameLayout> id=name1_1
                <FrameLayout> id=name1_2
```

И есть еще один фрагмент, который отдельно:

```
<CardView> id=name2
    <ImageView> id=name2_1
    <TextView> id=name2_2
    <TextView> id=name2_3
```

В своем **MainActivity** я могу получить элемент с **id=name1**, написав просто `findViewById(R.id.name1)`, с **name1_1** и **name1_2** - уже `findViewById(R.id.name1).findViewById(R.id.name1_1)`, например. 
Затем в коде я поступаю следующим образом:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.name1_2, new MyFragment())
                .commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Где **MyFragment** имеет разметку элемента c **id=name2**:

```
public class MyFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.name2, container, false);
```

В итоге, по идее, я должен буду получить элементы **name2_1** и **name2_2** вот так: `findViewById(R.id.name1).findViewById(R.id.name2).findViewById(R.id.name2_1)`, 
однако, `findViewById(R.id.name1).findViewById(R.id.name2)` возвращает нужный элемент, а вот `findViewById(R.id.name1).findViewById(R.id.name2).findViewById(R.id.name2_1)` уже возвращает **null**.

В чем проблема и как правильно достать из кода элементы **name2_1** и **name2_2**, с учетом подмены фрагментом? Если бы изначально была такая же иерархия, я бы получил нужный элемент, а пока что я получаю **null**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Неправильно извлекаете, надо извлекать `id` из вьюшки которую получили инфлейтом, типа:

```
public class MyFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.name2, container, false);
        View view_name2_1=v.findViewById(R.id.name2_1); 
    }
```

Comment: @Peter Samokhin Если Вы хотите обращаться в view не в том фрагменте или активити, где она заинфлейтена, то это уже архитектурно неверно как-то.

Comment: Почти ничего не понял. Но точно знаю, что стоит разобраться с change listeners в Realm для адекватного обновления данных.

Comment: `view_name2_1` сделайте членом класса и не парьтесь Извлечение происходит в одном месте, а используете где хотите